# How to do a "Select count..." with symfony and propel?

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

I'm trying to do a very simple sql query like this, to a propel Criteria :

```
SELECT count(id_user) FROM myTable WHERE id_page = 5
```

I did'nt found informations on the documentation.

Have you an idea ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(myTablePeer::ID_PAGE,5);
$count = myTablePeer::doCount($c);
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's one of those things that's really simple once you know how to do it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) based on your current ModelCriteria you can also perform

```
$yourCriteria->count();
```

This will return you the number of results.